# how to get the two value of spinner and get the value correspond?

Tags: android, spinner

i have 2 spinner in my code ... i work's perfectly... but my problem is i want to get the value of those spinner  correspond to mySpinner.getselecteditem() and mySpinners.getselecteditem()

answer will be appriciated..

@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the spinner in activity_main.xml
            Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);

```
        // Spinner adapter
        mySpinner
                .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        largelist));

        // Spinner on item click listener
        mySpinner
                    .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            final ImageView imview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                            TextView flavor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.flavor);
                            TextView Price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price);

                            flavor.setText("Flavor : "+large.get(position).getFlavor());
                            Price.setText("Price : "+large.get(position).getPrice());
                             String ids = large.get(position).getImageL();

                            ImageRequest ir = new ImageRequest(ids, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {

                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
                                    imview.setImageBitmap(response);

                                }
                            }, 0, 0, null, null);

                             AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(ir);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });



        Spinner mySpinners = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);

        // Spinner adapter
        mySpinners
                .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        largelist));

        // Spinner on item click listener
        mySpinners
                    .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            final ImageView imview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                            TextView flavor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.flavor);
                            TextView Price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price);
                            String price =  large.get(position).getPrice();
                            flavor.setText("Flavor : "+large.get(position).getFlavor());
                            Price.setText("Price : "+large.get(position).getPrice());
                            String ids = large.get(position).getImageL();

                            ImageRequest ir = new ImageRequest(ids, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {

                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
                                    imview.setImageBitmap(response);

                                }
                            }, 0, 0, null, null);

                             AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(ir);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });

        Spinner mySpinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        // Spinner adapter
        mySpinner2
                .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        largelist));

        // Spinner on item click listener
        mySpinner2
                    .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            final ImageView iview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                            //TextView flavor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.flavor);
                            //TextView Price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price);

                            //flavor.setText("Flavor : "+large.get(position).getFlavor());
                            //Price.setText("Price : "+large.get(position).getPrice());
                            String ids = large.get(position).getImageR();

                            ImageRequest ir = new ImageRequest(ids, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {

                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
                                    iview.setImageBitmap(response);

                                }
                            }, 0, 0, null, null);

                             AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(ir);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
                            mySpinner.getSelectedItem();
                            final String flavor1  = ids;
                            final String p = price;

                            Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

                            btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,tryonly.class);
                                    i.putExtra("price",p);
                                    i.putExtra("flavor", ids);
                                    startActivity(i);                                       
                                }
                            });

    }
```

Comment: What is happening now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String selected=largelist.get(mySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

Use this to get the selected string.

Comment: thank you for the response.! but the code you suggest only getting first index of the two spinners.. what i want is to get this on my first and second spinner   and pass to another activity....                                 flavor.setText("Flavor"+large.get(position).getFlavor());            Price.setText("Price : "+large.get(position).getPrice());